# How create polygons along line with fixed length on Postgis query or Leaflet(geojson)?

Tags: postgis

I have many lines in Postgis(with import in Geoserver). I need create(in new table) polygons(or buffers with fixed colors for count points in buffer) for each line with fixed length(1km, 100meters) without step. How can i create with query Postgis or may be with Leaflet(geojson from geoserver)?

Comment: Could you provide more explanation how it should look like? Maybe a mockup image?

Comment: ok, now i have polygon(from line buffer), i need split this polygon with fixed length(polygon-10km i need 10 polygons on 1km).

Comment: or may be cut line and then create polygon...?

Comment: cutting the line and then creating polygon sounds better but probably that would require somehow removing the parts of the buffers that intersect. If you want to split the buffer after creating it you'd have to generate a perpendicular line and split the polygon by that.

Comment: i know, and buffer is good, but i dunno how in postgis cut line or split buffer(polygon)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut the line you have to use `ST_LINE_Substring`

```
SELECT id,ST_Line_Substring(line,
  CASE WHEN i=0 THEN 0 ELSE (i*100)/ST_Length(line) END,
  CASE WHEN (i+1)*100<ST_Length(line) THEN ((i+1)*100)/ST_Length(line) ELSE 1 END),50,'endcap=flat')
FROM line, 
  (SELECT generate_series(0,floor(ST_Length(line)/100)::int) as i FROM line) as q
```

Getting `ST_Buffer` out of it is easy if you want it ended flat on both ends, it gets more complicated if you want something other than flat on the ends of the original line. Then we have to `ST_DIFFERENCE` then buffer with the buffer of the next/previous element and not forget about cases when there is only one fragment

```
WITH
line_frags AS
(
SELECT l.id,i, ST_Line_Substring(l.line,
CASE WHEN i=0 THEN 0 ELSE (i*100)/ST_Length(l.line) END,
CASE WHEN (i+1)*100<ST_Length(l.line) THEN ((i+1)*100)/ST_Length(l.line) ELSE 1 END) as frag,
CASE WHEN (i+1)*100>ST_Length(l.line) THEN true ELSE false END as the_end
FROM line AS l JOIN (SELECT id,generate_series(0,floor(ST_Length(l.line)/100)::int) as i FROM line AS l) as q ON q.id=l.id)

SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN f1.i=0 AND f2.i IS NULL 
    THEN ST_Buffer(f1.frag,50,'endcap=round')
  WHEN f2.i IS NOT NULL 
    THEN ST_DIFFERENCE(ST_Buffer(f1.frag,50,'endcap=round'),ST_BUFFER(f2.frag,50,'endcap=flat')) 
  ELSE 
    ST_Buffer(f1.frag,50,'endcap=flat') END as buf 
  FROM line_frags AS f1 
  LEFT JOIN line_frags AS f2 
    ON f1.id=f2.id AND (f1.i=0 and f2.i=1 OR f1.the_end AND f2.i=f1.i-1);
```